# Where to look for 'Gemalto PKCS11 Library' PPA, deb or snappy?

Tags: security, ppa, certificates, smartcard

I would like to find a trusted source for the files required to use Gemalto .NET smart card (libgtop11dotnet.so).
Unfortunately I cannot see them in the default repositories and cannot find them on Gemalto web page.

I've found following PPA, but not sure if it is the best trusted source:
https://launchpad.net/~arnaud-morin/+archive/ubuntu/gemalto

Comment: You may get to the right audiance in the security SE site: https://security.stackexchange.com

Comment: Is it possible to move the question there?

Comment: You'll need to flag a moderator, see here:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85017/how-do-i-move-my-own-question-to-another-stack-exchange-site

Comment: Or, simply delete this question and ask again on security SE

Comment: I'm fairly certain this question would not be on-topic at the security site. The question sounds on-topic here. @matandked Can you clarify what you mean by "trusted"?  Built by the developers?

Comment: By "trusted" in this context I mean something that will *not* open any vulnerabilities / will not cause losing of my data / spying on me / installing some spyware, malware, keylogger or anything harmful.